# ARP MAC address resolution request with no answer

Tags: networking, arp

What happens when a client broadcasts an ARP request (to whom's MAC this IP Address belongs) but does not receive any reply from the nodes in the subnet?

Comment: _[RFC 826, An Ethernet Address Resolution Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc826)_ explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

It won‘t be able to establish a connection to this machine as the MAC-Address is never resolved. There will be no entry in the ip route table.

The calling App will show an error after several retries.